# What is the reasoning for having form_with not generate any ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, actionview

The `form_with` helper doesn't generate `id`s for form elements, and therefore doesn't generate `for` attributes either. This differs from the old `form_tag` and `form_for` helpers.

If you want to use `form_with` instead of the deprecated `form_tag` and `form_for` helpers, but you want `id`s to generate, you need to add this to your config:

```rb
config.action_view.form_with_generates_ids = true
```

`id` generation is useful in some cases because certain front-end things may require it. On top of that, it seems to me that not generating `for` attributes means that forms generated with `form_with` have less a11y.

I'm currently working in an older codebase where form element `id`s are required, and my knee-jerk reaction is to enable the above config setting so I can use `form_with` without having to manually set IDs for every element.

What is the reasoning for making `form_with` not generate `ids` by default? I'm concerned that I'm missing something here, since I assume there's a good reason for the decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Rails 5.2 onwards, that actually *is* the default:

```rb
config.action_view.form_with_generates_ids = true
```

You can see it in the [release notes](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#action-view-notable-changes), along with the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/260d6f112a0ffdbe03e6f5051504cb441c1e94cd) that changed it. From the description of that commit:

> When `form_with` was introduced we disabled the automatic
> generation of ids that was enabled in `form_for`. This usually
> is not an good idea since labels don't work when the input
> doesn't have an id and it made harder to test with Capybara.
> You can still disable the automatic generation of ids setting
> `config.action_view.form_with_generates_ids` to `false.`

Doesn't seem like you're missing anything :D

Comment: Ah, yikes, looks like my confusion was a consequence of my being used to modern Rails, but working on a codebase that was running old Rails. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Yeah, that's happened to me too! No worries

Comment: This does not seem to be the default for me in Rails 6.1. `form_with` does not generate input `id`s, unless I use `fields_for` within that form. Adding the config and setting it to `true` does add the ids! Somehow it's not obeying the default.

Comment: Note: it's possibly because this is an updated old Rails app. Still, there was no config for `form_with_generates_ids` present in the app anywhere; it didn't generate them without me adding the config.

Comment: @nimmolo check to see `config.load_defaults` in `config/application.rb` is set to `5.2 or greater`. These are the [default values](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Comment: Aha, thanks @haley... I didn't know about that config! This app wasn't loading defaults for any version.